# how to remove last child when adding new item with jquery

Tags: jquery, append

I like to add dinamic li with jquery. I want to remove last position `li` when it reach 3 and keep append when I enter new value. But I have problem to deleting last position.

Is there any suggestion how to remove last position when add new item
thanks

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.search').on('click', function() {
    var text = $('#person').val();
    var li_count = $('ul.history li').length;
    $('#person').val('');
    if (li_count < 3) {
      $('ul.history').prepend('<li><a href="' + text + '">' + text + '</a></li>');
    } else {
      $('ul.history li:last-child').remove();
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="person" type="text">
<button class="search">search</button>
<ul class="history">
</ul>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are there, always prepend the searched text and remove if condition is achieved.

```
$('ul.history').prepend('<li><a href="' + text + '">' + text + '</a></li>');
if (li_count >= 3){
  $('ul.history li:last-child').remove();
}
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.search').on('click', function() {
    var text = $('#person').val();    
    $('#person').val('');    
    $('ul.history').prepend('<li><a href="' + text + '">' + text + '</a></li>');
    
    //Take latest length
    var li_count = $('ul.history li').length;
    if (li_count > 3){
      $('ul.history li:last-child').remove();
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="person" type="text">
<button class="search">search</button>
<ul class="history">
</ul>
```

Comment: I thought I still need else to removing last item. I see, so it will remove last item when reach 3. Thanks for suggestion